# MKAnnotation shows but does nothing on tap

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have added some pins on my map, but when I click them I do not see the title to show up.

I have set the `MKMapViewDelegate` and dragged it to self. This is my code.

```
-(void) setMapPoints:(NSMutableArray*)array
{
    for(int x = 0; x < array.count; x++)
    {
        ListEntry* entry = [array objectAtIndex:x];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
        coordinate.latitude = entry.latitude;
        coordinate.longitude = entry.longitude;

        NSString* name = entry.title;
        NSString* description = entry.address;

        MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate;
        annotation.title = name;
        [self.mainMap addAnnotation:annotation];
    }

  }

# pragma mark - mkanottationview delegate

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
NSLog(@"Annotation added");
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"Attraction"];
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    //annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"driveme"];
    return annotationView;
}
```

The Annotation Added message is printed but when tapping the pin, I do not see the bubble showing up with the title.

What do I miss? Once again, the delegate is set to self.

I try that on IOS 7.

Comment: Make sure annotation.title is not blank (callout won't show if title is blank).  Right before the addAnnotation line, put `NSLog(@"annotation.title.length = %d", annotation.title.length);`.  Does it log zero?

Comment: try this annotationView.enabled= YES;

Comment: @Anna that was it - make it an answer and I will accept it! Thanks!!